# function returning blank on running failing the check between 2 values

Tags: excel, vba

i m trying to pass a value from cell and check if its between the values of 2 columns and accordingly pull a 3rd cell value,
but it always returns blank , the value passed in is format 10:20:30 where 10 is degree 20 is min and 30 is seconds and `apple`
so the sheet where is has data is like

```
apple red new 0:00:00   5:00:00
apple blue new 5:00:00   8:00:00
apple green new 8:00:00   11:00:00
apple yellow new 11:00:00   15:00:00
bat red new 0:00:00   5:00:00
bat blue new 5:00:00   8:00:00
bat green new 8:00:00   11:00:00
bat yellow new 11:00:00   15:00:00
```

so the `output should be "green"` but its blank

```
Function FindMD(chkname As String, chkdegree As String) As String

Dim Result As String
Dim start_degree, end_degree
Dim count1, count2, count3, chkseconds1, chkseconds2, chkseconds3

For Each element1 In Split(chkdegree, ":")
        count1 = count1 + 1
        
        If count1 = 1 Then
        chkseconds1 = chkseconds1 + (element1 * 240)
        End If
         If count1 = 2 Then
        chkseconds1 = chkseconds1 + (element1 * 60)
        End If
         If count1 = 3 Then
        chkseconds1 = chkseconds1 + element1
        End If
 Next element1


For Each C In Worksheets("degrees").Range("A2:A250")

 If C.Value = chkname Then
 
 start_degree = C.Offset(0, 3).Value
 end_degree = C.Offset(0, 4).Value
 
    For Each element2 In Split(start_degree, ":")
           count2 = count2 + 1
           If count2 = 1 Then
           chkseconds2 = chkseconds2 + (element2 * 240)
           End If
            If count2 = 2 Then
           chkseconds2 = chkseconds2 + (element2 * 60)
           End If
            If count2 = 3 Then
           chkseconds2 = chkseconds2 + element2
           End If
    Next element2
 
    For Each element3 In Split(end_degree, ":")
           count3 = count3 + 1
           If count3 = 1 Then
           chkseconds3 = chkseconds3 + (element3 * 240)
           End If
            If count3 = 2 Then
           chkseconds3 = chkseconds3 + (element3 * 60)
           End If
            If count3 = 3 Then
           chkseconds3 = chkseconds3 + element3
           End If
    Next element3
    
    
         
    If chkseconds2 <= chkseconds1 Then
        If chkseconds1 < chkseconds3 Then        
        Result = C.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
         
 End If
Next C

FindMD = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Isn't one degree 3600 seconds (ie. 60x60) not 240?

Answer (score 0):

Really need to extract the degree >> seconds conversion to a function.

Untested:

```vb
Function FindMD(chkname As String, chkdegree As String) As String

    Dim Result As String, secIn As Long, c As Range
    
    secIn = DegreeToSec(chkdegree)
    For Each c In Worksheets("degrees").Range("A2:A250")
        If c.Value = chkname Then
            If secIn > DegreeToSec(c.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
                If secIn < DegreeToSec(c.Offset(0, 4).Value) Then
                    Result = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    FindMD = Result
End Function

Function DegreeToSec(d As String) As Long
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(d, ":")
    DegreeToSec = 3600 * arr(0) + 60 * arr(1) + arr(2)
End Function
```

Comment: To include the 'limits' it should be either `>=` or `<=`.